# Let: $f: [a , \infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_a^\infty f$ converge. Prove that $F(x) = \int_a^x f$ is a uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, integration, uniform-continuity

Can someone help me proving this problem?

Let  $f :[a , \infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_a^\infty f$ converge. Prove that 
$F(x) = \int_a^x f$ is a  uniformly continuous function in $[a,\infty)$.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $F(x)$ is continuous in $[a,+\infty)$ and the $\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)$ exists and it is finite.

Then use [Given a continuous function with an asymptote, prove that the function is uniformly continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684116/given-a-continuous-function-with-an-asymptote-prove-that-the-function-is-unifor)